# Keeping a session in all application life

Tags: android, session

I need to create a session and change it at times. In a specific activity should recover it and compare it to a different variable and modify the value of this session. I tried to create a class for this, but the change of activity, the value back to null. I need it to remain until the application is closed.

below:

```
import android.app.Application;

public class Util extends Application {
    private static String idCorrente;

    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        idCorrente="0";
    }

    public static String getIdCorrente() {
        return idCorrente;
    }

    public static void setIdCorrente(String id) {
        Util.idCorrente = id;
    }
}
```

I do not know exactly the right way to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store the data on the device somehow. I would recommend reading the [Storage Options](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html) page of the Android Developers Guide.

Specifically, I think you will find [SharedPreferences](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/data/data-storage.html#pref) well-suited for your application.

Comment: Thank you very much. It's working now. Just one more question. I am testing on the emulator, for real devices I need some kind of permission?

Comment: Whether or not you need to request [permissions](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/security/permissions.html) in your Manifest depends on what your application is doing. For a simple "Hello World" application, you don't need any permissions. Some activities such as using Bluetooth or using the devices' Internet connection will require permissions.

Comment: But in this case SharedPreferences writes a file saved on the device is that? in this case, do not need permission for that? write to this file?

Something like:
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_OWNER_DATA" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_OWNER_DATA" />

this is not necessary for this? I am sorry but I do not have a device to test now.

Comment: I do not believe you need any special permissions to use SharedPreferences. They are stored in the internal storage (so no need for WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE).